# Grails Spring Core Security Plugin - Unable to Resolve Classes

Tags: spring, security, grails, plugins

I'm using Grails 2.2.2 and I've already installed spring-security-core-2.0-RC2, by adding the below lines in my BuildConfig.groovy file:

```
Under the plugins:    
compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC2'

Under Repositories:
mavenRepo 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone'
```

The plugin was installed successfully and I've created the security Domains and Controllers using s2-quickstart script.

Now, I've updated one of my controllers with the below code:

```
import grails.plugins.springsecurity.Secured
@Secured(['ROLE_ADMIN'])
```

However when I try to run the application I get the below error:

> | Error Compilation error: startup failed: C:\workspace\SW
>   Development\Production\MyGrailsApp\safami\grails-app\controllers\safami\InfoPageAdminController.groovy:
>   4: unable to resolve class grails.plugins.springsecurity.Secured  @
>   line 4, column 1.    import grails.plugins.springsecurity.Secured

I'm new to Grails and I need your detailed solution.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The annotation was moved to a different package - change

```
import grails.plugins.springsecurity.Secured
```

to

```
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured
```