# Spring security import not working under grails 2.4.4

Tags: java, grails, spring-security

This is /not/ a duplicate of [Grails Spring Core Security Plugin - Unable to Resolve Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877725/grails-spring-core-security-plugin-unable-to-resolve-classes).

I am upgrading some code from grails 2.2.4 to grails 2.4.4 (java 7) and using the Spring Security plugins.

An import that worked under 2.2.4 began not working under 2.4.4, and I went looking for answers.

I have followed the answer at the link below

[Grails Spring Core Security Plugin - Unable to Resolve Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19877725/grails-spring-core-security-plugin-unable-to-resolve-classes),
 and changed

import grails.plugins.springsecurity.Secured

to

import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured

But the problem persists.  I am unable to use the @Secured annotations in my controller.

The error message is simple:

unable to resolve class grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured

From BuildConfig.groovy:

plugins {
...
compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC4'
...
}

I know RC5 is the latest, but for compatibility reasons with the searchable plugin I have to use RC4.

Please let me know if you need any other information.
@cfrick I am using Netbeans 8.0.2 :)

Comment: @cfrick is correct.  See https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/v2.0-RC4/src/groovy/grails/plugin/springsecurity/annotation/Secured.groovy#L15

Answer (score 1):

The annotation is [`grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured`](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/v2.0-RC4/src/groovy/grails/plugin/springsecurity/annotation/Secured.groovy) (plugin vs pluginS).  Please use an IDE :)

Comment: Even when I use the (Netbeans 8.0.2) IDE to import the Secured package by drilling all the way down to it, it still claims to be unable to resolve the class that Netbeans itself led me to.  I cleaned the application and it now runs, but Netbeans continues to complain about the import.

Comment: i'd suggest, you do a proper clean (e.g. `rm -rf target` and then do a `grails package`).  If netbeans is like intellij it might need a kick in the butt to reread the deps.